# popup_window_error: Error opening popup window in Teams App

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal, msal-react, azure-entra-id

So I have a react application where I used MSAL pop up flow. It works perfectly fine in a browser. But when I add it in Teams using teams manifest, it failed to open the popup with this error - `BrowserAuthError: popup_window_error: Error opening popup window. This can happen if you are using IE or if popups are blocked in the browser teams`.

Here is my manifest -

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.8",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "",
  "packageName": "com.microsoft.ixora.dfl",
  "developer": {
    "name": "I",
    "websiteUrl": "",
    "privacyUrl": ",
    "termsOfUseUrl": ""
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "",
    "full": ""
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "",
    "full": ""
  },
  "accentColor": "#5B5FC7",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "index",
      "name": "",
      "contentUrl": "",
      "websiteUrl": ",
      "scopes": ["personal"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [],
  "validDomains": ["", "login.microsoftonline.com"],
  "devicePermissions": ["openExternal"]
}
```

I have removed sensitive information's from here.

I have tried to open a popup with this code - `window.open("", "_blank", "height=600,width=400")`. Still got the same error. I have to use pop up flow as per the requirement.

From my research I have found that it is not  possible. Is there any alternative way to work with pop up workflow?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1.Check if popups are blocked in the browser used by Teams. Popups may be blocked by default in some browsers, including the embedded browser used by Teams. You can try disabling the popup blocker or adding an exception for your Teams app.
2. Modify your authentication flow to use a different method that does not rely on popup windows. Instead of using the popup flow, you can consider using the redirect flow, where the authentication process is redirected to a separate page and then redirected back to your app. This flow is more compatible with Teams and avoids the need for popup windows

Comment: Is there any way to disable the pop up blocker in Teams?

Comment: Hello @Khandakar Rashed Hassan

There are cases when popups are blocked in IE or Microsoft Edge, for example when a second popup occurs during multi-factor authentication. You will get an alert in the browser to allow for the pop-up window once or always. If you choose to allow, the browser opens the pop-up window automatically and returns a null handle for it. As a result, the library does not have a handle for the window and there is no way to close the pop-up window. The same issue does not happen in Chrome when it prompts you to allow pop-up windows.